# Is there way to use of hashed stored password in GlassFish & HTTP digest authentication?

Tags: java, glassfish, digest-authentication

I suppose that in HTTP digest authentication,
stored hashed password need to be
like "MD5(username + realm + password)".

GlassFish's JDBCRealm need to store password separately.
so, it must to be cleartext.

is it correct?
or is there way to use stored hashed password?

Comment: Can you clarify your first question with a concrete example? Concerning the GlassFish's JDBC Realm, you are wrong: it supports various digest algorithms, haven't you tried googling?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I know GlassFish supports many hash algorithms, and I tried with BASIC authentication, it works fine. and I had googling much, and found related URLs like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702258/jdbcdigestauthentication-only-works-when-providing-the-hash) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109308/http-digest-authentication) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257287/can-i-use-an-already-md5-encoded-password-in-digest-authentication) but seems to nobody succeeded with HTTP DIGEST authentication with hashed stored passwords.

Comment: as recent GlassFish 3.1.2 release, use of encrypted password are now possible. refer: [link](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/jdbc-realm-and-new-password-encryption-algorithm-field). but now i got a new problem of it with dynamic user addition because it used GlassFish's master password as encryption key. i don't know how to get GlassFish's master password from my application. any ideas?